# How can I get a subfield from value in json?

Tags: java, json

lets say I have

```
{
    "name": "Json",
    "detail": {
        "first_name": "Json",
        "last_name": "Scott",
        "age": "23"
    },
    "status": "success"
}
```

I want to get the name "Json" by the status if it is "success" if it is "terminal" or "running" I don't want to get the name. how is this achievable ?

Comment: From which field you want to get "Json" from name OR first_name?

Comment: from "name" field, could you also tell me how to get it from first_name? i think it should be a very similar way

Comment: I given my answer check it, i think it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JSON to a JSONObject, then you can get each value by its name:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonAsString);
String result = yourJsonObject.getString("name");
```

You can get the status object first in the same way, and check it's result and then get/don't get the name accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do it:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class JsonParser1 {

    static String js1 = "{\n"
            + "    \"name\": \"Json\",\n"
            + "    \"detail\": {\n"
            + "        \"first_name\": \"Json\",\n"
            + "        \"last_name\": \"Scott\",\n"
            + "        \"age\": \"23\"\n"
            + "    },\n"
            + "    \"status\": \"success\"\n"
            + "}";

    public JsonParser1() {
        parserJSON();
    }


    public void parserJSON() {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        try {
            Object obj1 = parser.parse(js1);
            System.out.println("User 1: " + obj1.toString());
            System.out.println();

            JSONObject jobj1 = (JSONObject) obj1;
            String name = jobj1.get("name").toString();
            String status = jobj1.get("status").toString();
            if (name.equals("Json")) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + name + "\t" + "Status: " + status);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JsonParser1();
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
User 1: {"name":"Json","detail":{"last_name":"Scott","first_name":"Json","age":"23"},"status":"success"}

Name: Json  Status: success
```

Comment: amazing stuff, thank you. this helps a lot and clears the basic concepts i was having an issue with

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

1. Create Class Files To Get Objects From JSON. (As Given Below)

   ```
   class ResponseObject implements Serializable {

   String name;
   Detail detail;
   String status;

   public ResponseObject() {
       this("", new Detail("", "", ""), "");
   }

   public ResponseObject(String name, Detail detail, String status) {
       this.name = name;
       this.detail = detail;
       this.status = status;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public Detail getDetail() {
       return detail;
   }

   public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
       this.detail = detail;
   }

   public String getStatus() {
       return status;
   }

   public void setStatus(String status) {
       this.status = status;
   }
   }

   class Detail implements Serializable {
   String first_name;
   String last_name;
   String age;

   public Detail() {
       this("", "", "");
   }

   public Detail(String first_name, String last_name, String age) {
       this.first_name = first_name;
       this.last_name = last_name;
       this.age = age;
   }

   public String getFirst_name() {
       return first_name;
   }

   public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
       this.first_name = first_name;
   }

   public String getLast_name() {
       return last_name;
   }

   public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
       this.last_name = last_name;
   }

   public String getAge() {
       return age;
   }

   public void setAge(String age) {
       this.age = age;
   }
   }
   ```
2. Parse JSON String and get objects using googles GSON As shown Below.

   ```
   String strResponse = "{ \"name\": \"Json\", \"detail\": { \"first_name\": \"Json\", \"last_name\": \"Scott\", \"age\": \"23\" }, \"status\": \"success\" }";


   try {

       ResponseObject responseObject = new Gson().fromJson(strResponse, ResponseObject.class);

       if (responseObject.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

           System.out.println(responseObject.getName());

           System.out.println(responseObject.getDetail().getFirst_name());

       } else {

           //status terminal

       }


   } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```